# Slick Carousel GoToSlide issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, slick.js

I have an issue with Slick Carousel, and I'm using Angular 4. I have Cards Carousel with names of Individuals and I have a search input.

Whenever I search for a name, The search Input loses focus and the goToSlide begins to animate to the name I have written.

Is there a way to keep focus on the input. The following is my code:

Search Input

```
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="search" [(ngModel)]="searchText" (ngModelChange)="onSearchPlayers($event)" #search>
```

And my search code, "onSearchPlayer()"

```
 onSearchPlayers(event) {
     this.results.filter(function(player, index){
       if (player.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
           $('.slick').slick('slickGoTo', index);
           setTimeout(() => {
               this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.search.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
           }, 5000);
       }
     })
  }
```

`this.results` is where I'm getting my data of individuals, and the `setTimeout` function is where I tried to focus on the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it by removing the `setTimeout` method from the Filter Function, since a Filter Fucntion is a void function.

```
onSearchPlayers(event) {
     this.results.filter(function(player, index){
       if (player.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
           $('.slick').slick('slickGoTo', index);
       }
     })

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.search.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
    }, 1000);
  }
```